# Choose seconds when pressing button in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a simple clickgame in Javascript and I want know, that when you press 'Start', a popup coming where you can choose between 5, 10 and 15 seconds. How can I simple create that? Also important is, that the Highscore is shown for each second you choose. Like when you choose 5 seconds: The Highscore for 5 seconds is: 10 clicks! When you choose 10 seconds: The Highscore for 10 seconds is: 20 clicks!

```js
let klick = 0;
let timerId = 0;

$("#start").click(function() { //clickfunktion beim starten.
    $("#start").fadeOut();
    $("#welcome").fadeOut();
    $("#time").fadeIn(900);
    $("#clicker").fadeIn();

    var display = document.querySelector('#time'); //referenz auf das Html attribut Time zum anzeigen.
    var dauer = 5;
    startTimer(dauer, display); //legt die zeit fest, und dass die Funktion gestartet wird.
})

function startTimer(dauer, display) {
    let timer = dauer;
    let sekunden;
    timerId = setInterval(function() {
        sekunden = parseInt(timer); //parseInt gibt eine ganze Zahl zurück
        display.textContent = sekunden; // zeigt sekunden-variable
        --timer; //setzt den timer immer einen herab
        if (timer < 0.00) {
            timer = dauer;
            $("#start").fadeIn();
            $("#welcome").fadeIn();
            $("#time").fadeOut();
            $("#clicker").fadeOut();
            $("#clicker").css("margin-top", "10%");
            $("#clicker").css("margin-left", "50%");

            alert("Sauber du hast " + klick + " klicks in 5 Sekunden geschafft!");
            alert('High Score ist ' + highScore(klick));

            klick = 0
            clearInterval(timerId);
        } //wenn timer auf 0 ist, wird alles wieder angezeigt und die Interval-Function beendet
    }, 1000); //zahl gibt an, wie oft die Function pro zeit wiederholt wird. Hier eine Sekunde (1000Millisekunden)
};

$("#clicker").click(function() {
    let zufall = Math.floor(Math.random() * 45) + 1 //setzt eine zufällige höhe für den clicker

    klick = klick + 1 //setzt den zähler beim klicken eins hoch
    $("#clicker").css("margin-top", zufall + "%");
    $("#clicker").css("margin-left", zufall + 45 + "%");
})

function highScore(score) {
  var saved = 0;
  saved = parseFloat(localStorage.getItem('highScore')) || 0;
  score = parseFloat(score) || 0;

  if (score > saved) {
    saved = score;
    localStorage.setItem('highScore', score);
  }
  return saved;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div><span id="time"></span> </div>
    <div id="welcome">Willkommen zu unserem Reaktionsspiel! Das Spiel startet, indem du dir eine Zeit aussuchst!</div>
    <button id="start" type=button >Start</button>
    <button id="clicker" type=button>KLICK</button>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

> ... a popup coming where you can choose between 5, 10 and 15 seconds

```
const fiveOrTenOrFifteen = () => (s = '' + prompt ('5, 10 or 15')) && s.match (/5|10|15/)
    ? s
    : s !== 'null' && fiveOrTenOrFifteen ()

console.log (fiveOrTenOrFifteen () || 'Canceled')
```

Comment: Well the window is popping up but have doing nothing :D

Comment: Well you need to enter 5, 10 or 15 then press OK

Comment: but it doesn't change the seconds and when I press cancel, the game starts and ignore it

Comment: You asked "how to choose" and got the answer. Stucked on something else? Ask again!